# Conflicting answers regarding system compability + refurbished laptop + 32/64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, computer-building, cpu-architecture

I've used SecurAble, system information and Regedit process to determine if I can install a 64-bit OS with my current configuration. SecurAble says it's expandable, but the other two say it's a x86 based PC.

[image]
<sup>**SecurAble/Registry Editor**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I'm adding the [Crucial Scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbZZQ.png) result as well.

Can anybody help to remove the conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official source for Intel product specifications, [ARK](https://ark.intel.com/products/71459/Intel-Core-i7-3630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz), the Intel Core i7-3630QM Processor has a 64-bit instruction set, so it supports installing operating systems that have a 64-bit architecture.

x86 is a family of backward compatible instruction set architectures based on the Intel 8086 CPU and its Intel 8088 variant. Versions of the x86 instruction set architecture have been implemented by Intel, AMD and several other vendors, with each vendor having its own family of x86 processors, including processors with the 32-bit instruction set and processors with the 64-bit instruction set.